# Why does subscription return all documents after using limit?

Tags: meteor

When I call:

```
//client
fetchNewDocuments(limit, skip, options){
  let a = Meteor.subscribe("items", limit, skip, options);
} 

//server
Meteor.publish("items", (limit, skip, options) => {
  if(limit || skip){
    console.log(`Limit: ${limit}, Skip: ${skip}`)
    return items.find(options, { sort: {dateCreated: -1}, limit, skip });
  }else{
    return this.stop();
  }
})
```

it returns 15 documents as expected, but when I add a function that renders more, such as this:

```
a(){
    this.fetchNewDocuments(this.state.limit, this.state.rendered, this.state.options);
    this.setState({ rendered : this.state.rendered + 15 })
  }
```

the server returns 30 documents instead of 15.

What is the problem for this error?  I would like it for it to return 15 all the time.  By the way, the limit never gets changed, so I am not sure as to why more than 15 gets rendered.

Comment: I don't think that the server sends the wrong number of documents. Do you ever unsubscribe from the previous subscription?

Comment: Isn't your issue coming from this :     this.setState({ rendered : this.state.rendered + 15 })
Not sure that's good practice. Try let `newRendered = this.state.rendered + 15; this.setState(() => ({ rendered : newRendered}))` tell me if it helps.

Comment: @MasterAM Isnt that what Im doing when I fetchDocuments withoout any parameters?  because it then does this.stop() in the publication callback.

Comment: @Ivo newRendered is the skip, not the limit

Comment: No, you need get the handle and unsubscribe using it, or use a library that does that for you (like [`react-meteor-data`](https://atmospherejs.com/meteor/react-meteor-data)), but note that changes to the wrapped component's own state won't work, as it depends on `props` from the parent.

Comment: @MasterAM Can you post a solution as to how I would do that?